# Difference between Slice up and Slice off

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Slice up/off some onions for me.
What would be more appropriate if both are correct and what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice up some onions, slice off a piece.  Slicing up is done to the whole onion, while slicing off yields a minor piece, leaving the rest of the whole intact.

> Slice up: cut into slices ([thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slice+up))